# Roles policy to access separate ARN resource issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-policy

I want to add policy that allow access IAM User only to few of the tables.

Follow [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingIAMWithDDB.html#access-control)

My policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmHistory",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "datapipeline:DescribeObjects",
                "datapipeline:DescribePipelines",
                "datapipeline:GetPipelineDefinition",
                "datapipeline:ListPipelines",
                "datapipeline:QueryObjects",
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1: xxxxxxxxxxxx:table:table/<TableName>", //commented real name
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/<TableName>" //commented real name
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As result I got "Not Autorized" message

[image]

But when I change Resource to "*" - all works.

So why I cant enable full read access only to separate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, thanks to **Deepesh S.** (from Amazon), listed below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ResourceBasedActions",
            "Action": [
                "datapipeline:DescribeObjects",
                "datapipeline:DescribePipelines",
                "datapipeline:GetPipelineDefinition",
                "datapipeline:QueryObjects",
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                 "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1: xxxxxxxxxxxx:table:table/<TableName>", 
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/<TableName>" 
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "NonResourceBasedActions",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmHistory",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "datapipeline:ListPipelines",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```